# Problema con getResource() al obtener una imagen

Tags: java, imagen, javafx, nullpointerexception

Tengo una paquete llamado app y dentro de este tengo dos paquetes uno llamado res y otro graficos, dentro de este útlimo tengo una clase con un metodo, que se encarga de crear un ImageView

```
private ImageView getImageViewFrom(String path){
    return new ImageView(getClass().getResource(path).toString());
}
```

Cuando lo llamo, le mado por argumento "../res/image.png" para obtener la imagen, sin embargo me lanza un NullPointerException en la linea de ese metodo, y no logró entender, el porque, es decir el archivo existe en app/res/image.png y la clase en app/graficos/GraphicLoader.java.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Clase GraphicLoader

```
package app.graficos;

import app.modelo.Juego;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException;

public final class GraphicLoader{

private GraphicLoader(){
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

public static GridPane createAndAddWithGraphics(Juego juego, GridPane gp){
    for(int i=0; i<juego.getTablero().getFilas(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<juego.getTablero().getColumnas(); j++){
            gp.add(getImageViewFrom("../res/0.PNG"));
        }
    }

    return gp;

}

private static ImageView getImageViewFrom(String path){
    return new ImageView(getClass().getResource(path).toString());
}
}
```

Comment: Bruno me parece que estas realizando algo incorrecto, ¿estas usando Android Studio? el directorio app/res/ es usado en android, confirma esto

Comment: No, no, estoy en IntelliJ IDEA, es para una aplicación de escritorio

Comment: @bruno Diaz martin Puedes poner la estructura de tu proyecto porque no tienes la ruta correcta

Comment: Ya he subido la estructura

Comment: @brunoDiazmartin me parece que el NullPointerException  puede no ser al crear el imageView, de hecho veo que la referencia es correcta de acuerdo a la estructura de tu proyecto "../res/image.png", agrega GraphicLoader por favor, imagino aquí es donde llamas el método getImageViewFrom() !

Comment: @Jorgesys Listo, clase añadida

Comment: @brunoDiazmartin no era "../res/image.png" la imagen que estabas tratando de cargar? esta fijo siempre la ruta de la imagen en esta línea: gp.add(getImageViewFrom("../res/0.PNG")); ?

Comment: @Jorgesys Si era esa, pero realmente me salta la exception con cualquier imagen, estaba probando pero me ocurre con todas

Answer (score 0):

La ruta para este caso es `\\app\\res\\image.png` pero una mejor manera de hacer esto es usando código para la obtener la ruta ya que debe tener la de donde este instalada y es así:

```
ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext)
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
String realPath = servletContext.getRealPath("/");

String path = realPath + "app" + File.separator + "res" + File.separator;
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema no es la referencia de tu archivo ya que es correcto el path definido de acuerdo a tu estructura de archivos.

```
"../res/<NOMBRE ARCHIVO DE IMAGEN>"
```

Lo que sucede es que en caso de no tener una ruta correcta, en este caso debes validar tu método:

```
 private ImageView getImageViewFrom(String path){
    URL imagePath = getClass().getResource(path);

    if(imagePath != null) {
        return new ImageView(imagePath.toString());
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Ahora si la ruta definida para imagen no existe puedes agregar o no el ImageView:

```
  if(getImageViewFrom("../res/0.PNG") != null){
      gp.add(getImageViewFrom("../res/0.PNG"));
  }else{
      //No agrega imagen.
  }
```

Comment: Pero porque tira NullPointerException si la ruta es correcta y el archivo existe?

Answer (score 0):

Toma en cuenta que en Java en general el recurso se busca en tiempo de ejecución relativamente a la ubicación del archivo `.class` y que los IDEs en tiempo de compilación generan los `.class` a la vez de copiar los recursos necesarios ¿en dónde? depende de cada IDE. Intenta localizar el archivo `GraphicLoader.class` y a partir de ahi revisa si se encuentra el archivo recurso.